# Unknown option: '--base-href' Angular 13 ng serve

Tags: angular

im creating an angular 13app using CLI i want to set a path to my app when i run it i got the following error :

```
Unknown option: '--base-href'
Unknown option: '/my-path/'
```

this is the command i run :

```
ng serve --base-href /my-path/
```

and

```
ng serve --base-href=/my-path/
```

and this are my dep :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "@reactivex/rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^13.0.1",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.8.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

any one have an idea about this isuue please and how i can set a path to my app in localhost ?

Regards

Comment: You can see the available options [in the docs](https://angular.io/cli/serve) (or run `ng serve --help`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks . i used  ng serve --serve-path=/my-path/ but it dose'tn server the app on localhost/my-path it shows the following message  : Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/my-path **

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This option has been deprecated. You should set it in `angular.json`, here :

```
    "acme-project": {
      [...]
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "baseHref": "/my-path/",
```

Comment: @ArnaudDenoylle thanks for your response i want to use the context path on my serve stage not "build"

Comment: @James Can you try ? usually, the "serve" config "extends" the "build" config so it might work in the serve stage

Comment: not it's not wotking :( open your browser on http://localhost:4200/

Comment: That's weird. I can confirm on my side that the difference comes from this param. If I add it, I get "open your browser on localhost:4200/my-path". Are you sure you did not forget to save the file ? Also, you can try to put this options directly under `architect.serve.options` but I don't like that. You can also try to set it on a new project, just to confirm

Comment: now it works i was missing / in the end "/my-path" instead of "/my-path/"  . thank you so much

Comment: In addition to the solution above, I had to change index.html `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/my-path/">`

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Arnauds answer.

**If you don't want to change the baseHref for your development and perhaps not all builds**,
you should **add baseHref to 'configurations' on selected config, and not to 'options.**

f ex: in my project AngularExamplesAndSnippets i add the baseHref to my "github-pages" configuration

> if you build for production you add it below "production"

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ... 
          },
          "configurations": {
            "github-pages": {
              "baseHref": "/AngularExamplesAndSnippets/",
              ...
            }
```

Comment: hello @JimiSweden , thanks for your respone. what represent the "github-pages" in your project ?

Comment: Thanks, this works for me, Angular 14. In my case is on "configurations": { "production": { "baseHref": .....