# Problem setting --base-href after migrating from Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript

I have recently migrated to v12 , and my build command is not working.

My old command used to be :

```
ng run my-app:build --configuration=dev --base-href=https://xxx.dev/preview/master/
```

Now, it fails with

```
> nx run my-app:build:dev --base-href=https://xxx.dev/preview/master/ --baseHref=https://xxx.dev/preview/master/
Property 'baseHref' does not match the schema.
{
  "type": "string",
  "description": "Base url for the application being built."
}'
```

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71604562/unknown-option-base-href-angular-13-ng-serve), but I want it to be dynamic based on the config that I provide.

Please help

Comment: why do you pass both `base-href` and `baseHref` ?

Comment: You have to remove the `=` -> `ng run my-app:build --configuration=dev --base-href https://xxx.dev/preview/master/`. You also need to remove the `baseHref` in the `Angular.json` file since it's useless - in this case.